# Variable uninitialized - must I set a variable, rather than just add to it in an if statement?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I'm trying to build a basic weight calculator and came across "variable weightOut might not have been initialized" error. Google seems to indicate that this is because I need to initialize "weightOut" rather than just set it " = weightIn * .78 " . Is this true? Here is my code.

```
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

          int weightIn, planetNumber;
          double weightOut;

          System.out.print("What is your weight? ");
          weightIn = keyboard.nextInt();

          System.out.println("I have information for the following planets: ");
          System.out.println("   1. Venus ");
          ...

          System.out.print("What planet are you going to? ");
          planetNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

          if( planetNumber == 1 )
          {
              weightOut = weightIn * 0.78;
          }
          ...

         System.out.println("Your weight would be " + weightOut + 
                  " on that planet.");
```

Comment: The value of `weightOut` at the time of deceleration is unknown (this is true for all local variables).  The compiler is concerned that you might rely on this value some where in your code while it's in an unknown state. Personally, I think you should initialise it to be sure unless you provide a default value in a `else` branch of you your `if` statements that provides a default value

Comment: Ah! Hold on then, my current else statement is 


              else
              {
                  System.out.println("I don't understand.");
              }

Could I change it to

    else
    {
    weightOut = 0
    }

To yield no errors?

Comment: You'd probably find that the compiler would stop complaining then...

Comment: But it would be bad form, I'm sure? I suppose it's interesting to know how to get around the compiler errors but the purpose of this is to learn good code, so I will follow the other answers and make initializing a habit. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't do, it makes it unclear if you code runs for multiple pages as to what the value actually means.  It's also a lot safer, IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables are not initialized with default values.Local variables should be initialized before use .

```
double weightOut = 0.0;
```

What if the `if` statement never really executed at run time ?  The compiler is actually worried that in case during run time the local variable fails to get a value and you use it some where else , what value it should have given it doesn't have a default value !

Comment: +1 for *What if the if statement never really executed at run time ?* - Also note that `weightIn` might be not successfully read.

Comment: That makes sense, but shouldn't I set weightOut = 1, because otherwise won't my if statements all result in 0?

Furthermore, why then when I set weightOut = 1 at the beginning of my code, I don't get an error for weightIn and planetNumber? Is it because depending on a scanner input is less, I dunno, tricky than depending on a variable that depends on a scanner input?

EDIT: Ah, I see that weightOut will not be 0  if I set weightIn 0 initially because it should be changed by the scanner input. This is becoming more clear now, thank you.

Comment: @komali_2 That depends on your logic !

Answer (score 2):

In java method/local variables should be initialized. Uninitialized variables can give unexpected results and hence this is raised. In your code the value of `weightOut` will never be set if the enclosing `if` conditions is not met. You need to initialize the following variable with some default value:

```
  int weightIn = 0;
  int planetNumber = 0;
  double weightOut = 0.0d;
```

Answer (score 2):

What value will the the variable have if you don't enter the if-branch?

To fix this, add an else-branch at the end:

```
if (...)
    myVar = x;
else if (...)
    myVar = z;
else
    myVar = y;
```

Setting the value in an else-branch rather than setting some default initial value not only makes the compiler happy but also prevents you from committing the error that the compiler is complaining about: if at some later point you add code that uses the variable before its correct value is set in the if statement you would still get an error message from the compiler and not an unexpected result when running the program.

Comment: Ah, I had an else statement, I just did not include it, but that is true thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize "weightOut" to 0, because local variable can not be used without initializing.
As in your case you are assigning value in if condition and that one is not valid because **in java value of local variable is decided at run time**. That is the reason u are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

What if the planet number is 0?

You should do:

> double weightOut = 0;